# How do I check a variable is not null before doing another check?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
if (App.selectedPhrases != null && App.selectedPhrases.Count != 0)
```

Is there a way I can simplify that using the ? operator to check for null rather than have two different checks with an && joining them?

Comment: Try `if (App.selectedPhrases?.Count > 0)` - the `?.` part is what works, but it will make the whole expression, ie. `App.selectedPhrases?.Count` be `null` if `App.selectedPhrases` is `null`). That's why I switched to `>`, as `null != 0`.

Comment: A better approach would be to make sure there is always a collection instance present in `App.selectedPhrases`. I doubt you're distinguishing between `null` and `0` in any meaningful way,

Comment: I agree with Lasse, that >0 is an better approach, since count can’t be less than 0 but null, if you use ?

Comment: It's not a simplification by any means (so not putting it up as an answer) but since you wanted to use the null-conditional operator, I suppose you could do something like `if (new List<int?> { null, 0 }.Contains(App.selectedPhrases?.Count))`

Comment: @WimOmbelets I believe you mean *if **not** contains*

Comment: @Rafalon oh yeah that's what I meant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the null conditional member access operator (`?.`) to conditionally access a member only if it is not null, like so

```cs
if (App.selectedPhrases?.Count > 0)
```

I decided to use `>` instead of `!=` as the `Count` of a collection cannot be smaller than 0, and `null != 0` is true, which is incorrect in our case

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with this:

```
// So if it's null, then return 0 so that the second check will not be true
if ((App.selectedPhrases?.Count ?? 0) != 0) {
   // Do stuff  
}
```

Comment: This code will not compile 'Operator ?? cannot be applied to operands of type int? and bool'.

Comment: Quite right! I updated with working code. I did not account for the order of operators.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (App.selectedPhrases?.Count > 0)
```

Or:

```
if (!(new List<int?>{null, 0}.Contains(App.selectedPhrases?.Count)))
```